# Discord bot traceback key error: '736458231848894534'

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make a Discord bot with a youtube tutorial for economy bots, but I got the following error:

> Ignoring exception in command balance: Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85,
> in wrapped
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\polly\OneDrive\Documents\HACK\Discord
> Bot\Python\currency.py", line 22, in balance
> wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] KeyError: '736458231848894534'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939,
> in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line
> 863, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)   File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94,
> in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: KeyError: '736458231848894534'

HERE IS THE PART WITH THE ERROR:

```
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color = discord.color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank balance", value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)


async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0
```

Can anyone help? I can't proceed if this error isn't resolved.
Thanks!

Comment: Please search for the error online, you will get lots of info explaining what it means. Then, extract a [mcve] from your code which helps you concentrate on the issue and which you can add to your question here, too. As it stands above, your question is off-topic. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've messed up your own naming scheme! As far as I can see `user` is a `discord.Member` object (**not assignable**, this is where your error comes from) and `users`, which is a list of `discord.Member`. Make sure to use the right one, for each case. You can only index a list, yet you're trying to index your `user` object. Replace you single `user` with `users` in the relevant places

```
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", color = discord.color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "Bank balance", value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)


@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author

    earnings = random.randrange(101)


    await ctx.send("Someone gave you {earnings} kash")



    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("mainback.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0


    with open("mainback.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True
```